# Extending default template Odoo 12

Tags: themes, odoo, extend, odoo-12

I'm just following the tutorial step by step and even in this way I'm getting an error. Here in Extend the default Header chapter     ->    https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/themes.html#extend-the-default-header

In Website/Configuration/Apps I install my theme, and then in Website/Configuration/Settings  I click the button Choose Theme, and once there I select my theme for use.

However at this point an error message like this appears:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 735, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record, data_node)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
    model = self.env[rec_model]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'theme.ir.ui.view'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 653, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 312, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 695, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 344, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 938, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/website_theme_install/models/ir_module_module.py", line 356, in button_choose_theme
    self._theme_upgrade_upstream()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/website_theme_install/models/ir_module_module.py", line 314, in _theme_upgrade_upstream
    upper_theme.button_immediate_upgrade()
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 71, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 596, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 535, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 422, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 318, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 224, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 801, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 864, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 757, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 735, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record, data_node)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
    model = self.env[rec_model]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "theme.ir.ui.view" while parsing None:4, near
<data inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">
  <!-- Assign an id  -->
  <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="id">my_header</attribute>
  </xpath>
  <!-- Add an element after the top menu  -->
  <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header/div" position="after">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="alert alert-info mt16" role="alert">
        <strong>Welcome</strong> in our website!
      </div>
    </div>
  </xpath>
</data>
```

What am I doing wrong? is it me or the tutorial is not updated?

Just to clarify, although at the bottom of the traceback appear a `<data></data>` tags, it's only here where is like this, because in my code at that position I have a `<template></template>` tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hours searching on the Internet for an answer to my question. I found that the problems were two in fact.

The first one is the need to append the **'website_theme_install**' app in my *depends* in the ***manifest**.py*. It's not said anywhere in the tutorial, and I don't know why it was already installed in my Odoo instance, maybe is default in Odoo 12.0. This is what caused the `KeyError: 'theme.ir.ui.view'`.

The second was the fact that in the *website.layout* template which is itself inherited from the *portal.frontend_layout* template there is no div after the header, actually there we have a nav, but not a div just after the header like was searched here:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header/div" position="after">
```

So I had to change it to:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header/nav" position="after">
```

Cause there was a nav at that position. Didn't changing this was throwing a *ParseError*.

After change this it was working perfectly.
Hope this can be helpful for others

Comment: You saved me ton of time right now. This is the most complete answer on this subject, and this will work just fine (just tested and it works at this moment). Initially, I was impressed with odoo, and I decided to use it for one of my projects, but unfortunately, their documentation seems more then obsolete. You will find lot of these things (not only theme building related), instead with almost everything else you want to customize by programming.

Comment: I'm very happy that this was useful to someone. You're right the Odoo's documentation is full of situations like this, and soon or later everyone of us must get use to it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, trying very similar thing with 12.0 Community, same result, anyone know what's going on?  I'm using a tutorial making this change:

```
<template id="mystyle" name="My style" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
    <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/theme folder/static/scss/style.scss"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: I found the issue for me, I have an addon that extends website.assets_frontend, and, so the theme must have a 'depends' entry for that theme so it extends this template.

Answer (score 0):

You can install theme as module, not thrue Theme Installer module.

In `Apps` click `Update Apps List` and search your module, then install.
For that installation not need dependency `website_theme_install`